# Informatica error database driver error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a question regarding a failure while executing my workflow. The workflow has existed for years and was working fine. But suddenly today I am facing an error while executing. The mapping has a stored procedure which is the reason for the failure. Please find the error message below and let me know if I can resolve this

```
"Message Code: CMN_1022
Message: Database driver error...
CMN_1022 [
ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist
ORA-06512: at "schema_name.sp", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 2
Database driver error...
Function Name : ExecuteSP

Oracle Fatal Error
Database driver error...
Function Name : ExecuteSP
Oracle Fatal Error]"
```

The stored procedure (`schema_name.sp`) truncates some existing tables based on a condition. Unfortunately I don't have access to view the procedure.

When I tried searching about the fatal error, I found that the fatal error is because of connectivity problem. Let me know if that is true.

Comment: Well, without seeing the query, and relevant code, who knows.

Comment: `Specified partition does not exist` sounds like a dba problem to me. Are  you the dba? Else raise a ticket to your dba team. Good luck.

Comment: You have to trust the ORA- error message: there is a problem on line 9 of that procedure.  If you don't have access to the code then you can't troubleshoot the problem.